# Can't change language inputs on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS after computer wakeup

Tags: keyboard, suspend, language-support

When my laptop wakes up it reverts to my default language input / keyboard (Danish) instead of my external keyboard (English UK) and it's not possible to change this (i.e. changing it to English US for example still uses the Danish keyboard layout). I have no idea why this would be, but it seems that Ubuntu generally doesn't like being woken up (I had wifi problems in the past which required restarting).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem switching between English and Spanish keyboard layouts. Based on the answer at: https://askubuntu.com/a/1232819/264753, I regenerated my locales with:

```
sudo locale-gen
```

and it seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try IBus input method. Helped for me: [IBus input method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxdo1.png)

Comment: Seems I was already using IBus - thanks for the help though!